# Term for marking stating the date or year something was built or established

Tags: phrase-requests

An arch might be engraved with "MCMLXII". A company logo might say, "since 1873".  A sidewalk might be stamped with "08/2012".  What do you call these markings?

Comment: I think they're dedications. Need to double check before posting as an answer.

Comment: They're also in coins. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the generic term for this could be a date stamp.

Specifically for buildings, the stone upon which the date built is engraved is called a cornerstone or a ceremonial stone.  This stone often was an important marker in the construction of the building, and all measurements would be made from this stone.

Comment: Much as I'm a fan of cornerstones (no, really), I don't think this quite answers the OP's question... He's asking about the date on the cornerstone, not the cornerstone itself...

As for date stamp, that seems to literally refer to dates that have been stamped on (or look like they have been), eg. on food packaging - do you have a different definition for that somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

**[*"Datemark"*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/datemark)** is defined as:

*"a marking that indicates the date of a thing; specif :  a mark on gold and silver plate indicating date of manufacture"*, e.g.:

> *The thieves took a decorative hopper and lead downpipes, one of which had been stamped with a datemark of 1720.*

Answer (score 0):

It is called simply "date"

Date:  an inscription on a writing, coin, etc., that shows the time, or time and place, of writing, casting, etc.

Source: Webster Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Well I have bought a few and they are often referred to as [Circa Signs](https://www.google.com/search?q=circa%20building%20sign&client=firefox-a&hs=qbU&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=0007U8y9JejL2QWLp4G4BA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=928#channel=sb&q=%22circa%20sign%22&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch).  There might be an older term but I think this is what you would use now if trying to buy one.